# Как узнать обрезан текст или поместился в <Text/> после сокращения с помощью ellipsizeMode и numberOfLines?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Всем привет. Есть текстовое поле, в котором может быть много или мало текста. Если текста много, он обрезается с помощью атрибутов ellipsizeMode и numberOfLines

```
<Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='tail'>Очень длинный длинный длинный текст</Text>
```

или

```
<Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode='tail'>Короткий текст</Text>
```

Как программно узнать был ли текст обрезан?
Смысл показывать стрелку свернуть/развернуть, если текст обрезан или не показывать, если он вместился.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962147/react-native-determine-when-text-is-cut-off/38812442#38812442

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2496